# rails observe_field using ActionView Helpers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, select

I have a select Menu with a few options

```
  <p>
    <%= f.label :reason %><br />
    <%= f.select :reason, Confirmation.reasons.collect {|p| [ p[:name], p[:id] ] }, { :include_blank => true } %>
  </p>
```

The last being id "5" and name = "Other"

If and only if they choose other I want a hidden text_area with a div id = "other" to be shown to allow the user to type...

How can I do this simply?

```
  <%= link_to_function "Show me other" do |page| 
    page[:other].toggle
  end %>
```

I can toggle it but I want to show it on the selection of the "Other" in the select box?  Is this a job for observe_field?

Comment: but observe_field uses ajax?  what would be the client side only equivalent?

Comment: <%= f.select :reason, Confirmation.reasons.collect {|p| [ p[:name], p[:id] ] }, { :include_blank => true }, { :onchange => "$('otherform').show();" } %> works for the entire form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own answer is fine, but for future reference, [observe_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001654) doesn't have to make an Ajax call. You can use `:function` to specify JavaScript code to run locally instead.

e.g.

```
<%=observe_field 'reason', :frequency => 1, 
    :function => "if ($('reason').value == '5') { $('otherform').show(); } else { $('otherform').hide(); }" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= f.select :reason, Confirmation.reasons.collect {|p| [ p[:name], p[:id] ] }, { :include_blank => true }, { :onchange => "if (this.value == '5') { $('otherform').show(); }" } %>
```

Got it!